# nth-child not working? and image not properly align to the text

Tags: html, css

Why is my nth-child not working here I mean it do apply the first one but it also applies to the rest of the child also why is my image is not align to the text, its a little bit higher than the text.

HTML

```
     <div class="skillSet"> 
        <h2> Skill set </h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h3 class="progLang"> HTML </h3>
                <p class="abbr"> (Hypertext Markup Language) </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3 class="progLang"> CSS </h3>
                <p class="abbr"> (Cascading Style Sheet) </p>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
```

CSS

```
.skillSet {
    margin: 6rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
    padding: 8px;
}

.skillSet h2 {
    border-left: 8px solid black;
    text-indent: 0.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.skillSet ul {
    margin: 1rem 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.progLang:nth-child(1) {
    color: #f06529; 
}

.progLang:nth-child(1):after {
    content: url("html5-icon.png");
}

.progLang:nth-child(2) {
    color: #264de4;
}

.progLang:nth-child(2):after {
    content: url("css-icon.png");
}

.abbr {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

it seems like Im using it, is my syntax incorrect or am I not properly using it?

Comment: Because _every_ `.progLang` element you got there, _is_ the first child of its parent.

Comment: `nth-child` means the nth child in a parent. If you want the `h3` in the second `li` item, use `li:nth-child(2) h3` for a selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nth-child selector targets the specified element based on its position among its siblings. However, in your HTML structure, the .progLang elements are not direct children of the same parent. They are actually children of the li elements. To target the .progLang elements correctly, you need to adjust your selector.

The image alignment issue might be due to the default vertical alignment of inline-level elements. You can adjust the vertical alignment of the image by using the vertical-align property.

```css
.skillSet {
    margin: 6rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
    padding: 8px;
}

.skillSet h2 {
    border-left: 8px solid black;
    text-indent: 0.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.skillSet ul {
    margin: 1rem 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

li:nth-child(1) .progLang {
    color: #f06529; 
}

li:nth-child(2) .progLang {
    color: #264de4;
}
.progLang:nth-child(1):after {
    content: url("html5-icon.png");
}

/* Adjust vertical alignment of images */
.progLang:after {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 5px; /* Add some spacing between text and image */
}

.progLang:nth-child(2):after {
    content: url("css-icon.png");
}

.abbr {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="skillSet"> 
        <h2> Skill set </h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h3 class="progLang"> HTML </h3>
                <p class="abbr"> (Hypertext Markup Language) </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3 class="progLang"> CSS </h3>
                <p class="abbr"> (Cascading Style Sheet) </p>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
```